# Interchangeability of Past Continuous or Past Simple for Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: american-english, continuous, perfect-continuous

Yesterday an American friend of mine shuttered my world by saying that these three tenses (past continuous, past simple, present perfect continuous) are interchangeable in American English.

So if I were to say, for instance, to a friend who showed up on my doorstep an hour later than we arranged:

> **I was waiting for you for an hour!**

or

> **I waited for you for an hour!**

that would be as grammatically correct as

> **I've been waiting for you for an hour!**

Is it always acceptable to use past continuous or past simple instead of present perfect continuous? I guess it's perfectly normal in an informal conversation but would it be just as good in formal context (i.e. an official letter, a paper etc)?

Comment: For that specific sentence, they are indeed all used in AmE and mean nearly the same thing. But you can't (for example) replace *"I saw Tarantino's latest movie yesterday"* by *"I have been seeing Tarantino's latest movie yesterday."*

Comment: I believe you meant to say that your friend "shattered" your world, although I have trouble grasping how a simple point about grammar could be earth-shattering, even in a figurative sense.

Comment: You should ask basic questions about the relationship of tense and aspect on [ell.se].

Comment: I believe that the idiosyncrasies of different dialects of English well deserve to be here - after all, I'm not asking which tense to use for a situation. If the proposition turns out to be true it'll be huge for many people.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL  What do you mean it will be huge? It’s not a big deal, just how it happens to work out in this situation. Nobody would even notice.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean (a) are all three tenses acceptable in this sentence? ***yes!*** (b) are all three tenses interchangeable in any sentence in which they appear? ***absolutely not!*** I assume that your friend meant (a), in which case she's correct.

Comment: @tchrist it's still huge for thousands of students who learned English from Murphy's textbook (and not only that - I studied with three or four popular textbooks as well and there's not a word about this thing) and didn't happen to ask this question.

Comment: @PeterShor As a matter of fact, I thought something in between. I asked if these tenses could be interchanged in most situations - more specifically, if it's acceptable to use PS or PP any time instead of PPC (Present Perfect Continuous). I guess, I should edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: That's not true. *"I have been working for five hours straight, and I need a break"* should not be replaced by past simple. But quite often, two or more tenses are possible (and the same is true in British English, although the specifics may differ).

Comment: @D4RKS0UL Is it acceptable to use PS or PP any time instead of PPC (Present Perfect Continuous)? No. I think you're falling into a common trap many people (especially non-native speakers) seem to think: *tense+aspect* dictates the reality. In fact, it's the thought that dictates *tense+aspect*.

Comment: @PeterShor Unfortunately, I don't understand why it's ok to use PS or PP instead of PPC in my example and it's not in the one you provided.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: This part "I asked if these tenses could be interchanged in most situations - more specifically, if it's acceptable to use PS or PP any time instead of PPC" sounds to me like you're thinking that the relationships between situations and tenses/aspects are one-to-one, but that's not how it really works.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ok, HOW does it work? Could you be so kind to give me a link on an article - I really don't understand why it can be applied in my example but it can't be in the example other participants provided, nor I really understand "the relationships between situations and tenses/aspects are one-to-one" part. I guess that's why I never saw any of this in textbooks—it's easier to enforce simple guidelines instead of explaining when you can fiddle with the rules and swap one time instead of another.

Comment: I don't have a single article that covers all of it, or frankly, a good portion of it, that is any better than a common website for ELLs. (If you really want to get to the bottom of it, imho, you can expect several books.) The hint in my first comment comes from my own experience. The fact that you never saw any of this in textbooks makes a lot of sense. Because I haven't seen the matter covered satisfactorily in a short article before. The best book I've found that covers deep enough details about English verbs (tenses and aspects) is *Meaning and the English Verb* by Geoffrey Leech.

Comment: On the other hand, if you only want to know why in that specific situation, the three alternatives can work equally well, I believe that either ELU or ELL can answer your question well enough. But the Q&A format is perhaps not ideal to cover all of them in all possible, general cases. (This is not to say that it's impossible; I believe it may be possible that someone could point it out in a few short paragraphs. I'd like to read such an answer, too.)

Answer (score 1):

There are several categories of appropriateness: appropriate for writing and speech, appropriate for writing, appropriate for speech, and appropriate for neither. (Of course, the lines between them are not always clear.) For various reasons, it's much easier to find written explanations of what is appropriate for writing (or both writing and speech) than of what is appropriate in speech. Paradoxically, what happens in informal circumstances is sometimes only studied formally (by academics).

As you noted in your answer, all three sentences are quite appropriate for speech, whose importance is not to be minimized, because there are many possible utterances that are not. I think that's because in each case, you can come up with an interpretation in which the meaning is actually correct:

*I was waiting for you for an hour!* (Then I turned around, and you were there.)

*I waited for you for an hour!* (Then I turned around, and you were there.)

The reasons they're not appropriate in writing is that (a) you have time to come up with the **most** fitting way to describe what just happened and (b) you are writing in a medium that makes it a little less obvious what's going on (because the reader can't see you), so you're expected to put in extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is not grammatically correct. Present Perfect Continuous denotes an action in the past that continues right up to the present or has just  completed.

I've yet to find any reputable grammar source (American or not) affirming that Past Simple or Past Continuous convey this meaning.

People (including native speakers) simply use all kinds of bad grammar -- especially when we speak colloquially.

Comment: The thing is that she claims to be a Grammar Nazi and says that it's grammatically correct.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL Well then, I think it's up to her to step up and back up the assertion with a reputable source.

Comment: it's exactly the problem - there are so few books on the grammar of American English it's just confounding.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL All three are perfectly grammatical because they are things that one native speaker could produce in that circumstance and have it clearly understood by another native speaker without loss of meaning or intent. And as Peter Shor notes, they all mean pretty much the same thing in actual day-to-day practice for this scenario. Furthermore, this is not something unique to the United States; it’s just how English is.

Comment: The thing is that I got my initial knowledge about English tenses from R. Murphy's textbook and it was pretty rigid on that matter. Some may argue that it's not that advanced a book but I've studied with Advanced Grammar In Use and there's no mention of this as well. It's not that obvious a thing for a foreigner. The fact that no one did as much as put an asterisk with a single line that sometimes these tenses could be interchanged is a shocker (since otherwise those two are very thorough textbooks).

Comment: @DARKSOUL: There were undoubtedly guidelines: use the present perfect if A is the case, and the past if B is the case. Didn't they say anything about what happens when A and B are both true?

Comment: @PeterShor oops, sorry for the delay - I somehow missed that comment. No, not a word in any textbook I've studied so far.

Comment: @DARKSOUL: then the textbooks are handing you an insoluble problem. You are faced with the dilemma of choosing *the* one correct tense, when a large fraction of English sentences have more than one correct tense, and there's probably no good way of choosing between them.

Comment: Be they American, British, Nigerian, Indian, or South African, persons do not walk around with grammar rule books in their pockets. The reality is that _there are no rules, only usages._ As time goes by, you'll appreciate the freedom intrinsic to your shattered world.